# SQL count with where clause to find a Single Rows in a Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have table called Details. Sample records as follows

```
ID        PNO    ActionsTaken    
52101    2       Received  
52101   5       Received  
52101   3       Received  
52101   3       Send To HO  
52101   3       Send to RD  
52101   7       Received  
52101   8       Received  
35501   2       Received  
35501   7       Received  
35501   7       Send To HO
```

I need to query records as follows

```
ID    PNO    ActionsTaken
52101    2       Received
52101    5       Received
52101    7       Received
52101    8       Received
35501    2       Received
```

ActionTaken is only "Received" not get another action like "Send to HO" or Send to RD".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table contains **7 records** with **[ActionsTaken]** as "Received". But the result set need only **5 records** with **[ActionsTaken]** as "Received", which means result need to have **[ActionsTaken]** as "Received" and that **[ID]** and **[PNO]** should not have **[ActionsTaken]** other than "Received".

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM [Table] T1
 WHERE T1.ActionsTaken = 'Received'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT TOP 1 NULL
                      FROM [Table] T2
                     WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
                       AND T2.PNO = T1.PNO
                       AND T2.ActionsTaken <> 'Received'
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

your query is

`Select * from Details where ActionsTaken = 'Received'`

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select ID,PNO from @Table1 where ActionsTaken <> 'Received'
)

select T.* 
from @Table1 T
left join CTE c on t.ID=c.ID AND t.PNO = c.PNO
 WHERE c.ID IS NULL
```

Explanation :-

In the code snippet, I used CTE to get  ID,PNO of all the records which does not have the value 'Received'.
So in this case, there will be 2 records in the CTE which is

```
ID     PNo
52101  3
35501  7
```

In the next sql statement, it is left joining the main table with cte. 
without the WHERE condition(c.ID IS NULL) the result set will be

```
ID        PNO    ActionsTaken    ID    PNo
52101    2       Received        NULL  NULL
52101    5       Received        NULL  NULL
52101    3       Received        52101 3
52101    3       Send To HO      52101 3
52101    3       Send to RD      52101 3
52101    7       Received        NULL  NULL
52101    8       Received        NULL  NULL
35501    2       Received        NULL  NULL
35501    7       Received        35501 7
35501    7       Send To HO      35501 7
```

Now when the WHERE condition (c.ID IS NULL) is applied, we will get the records with ActionTaken is only "Received".

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This code also work. But I am new to SQL therefore I cant Understand how it works. Thanks Lot Siya.

Answer (score 0):

**cte does not works with my sql, so, without cte:**

SELECT DISTINCT [d1].*
FROM @Details AS [d1] LEFT JOIN @Details AS [d2] 
ON [d1].[id] = [d2].[id] AND [d1].[pno] = [d2].[pno] and [d2].[ActionsTaken] <> 'Received'
WHERE [d1].[ActionsTaken] = 'Received' AND [d2].[id] IS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

@juozas The Op doesn't want to take distinct records, he just wants records with actions_taken as received, so this is perfect for the question:

```
SELECT ID,PNO,ActionsTaken FROM Details WHERE ActionsTaken = 'Received';
```